# Elastic Beanstalk pull application files locally

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to get the current files on my elastic beanstalk instance. I would like to use the command line tools for this instead of manually uploading a zip each time. I currently have a environment set up.

Things already set up:

**eb version 3.4.4**

git init

eb init

eb create dev-env

---

However, I do not get any of my files in the local folder. All I've created so far is the dev environment which eb sets up for me. Is there a way to pull the current files or do I just have to download the latest zip on production and paste it in my local folder and git push from that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a command for that in the "labs" command section.

```
eb labs download
```

It works best if you have an empty directory. (except for the .elasticbeanstalk folder of course)